# Azure DevOps deploy to function - multiple zip packages

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have a large code repository that I need to deploy to an Azure function. Due to the size of the code, I've had to split the build into 3 separate build pipelines and artifacts, I am aware that there is a zip 2048Mb hard limit that cannot be 'bypassed' in any way.

However, now I am struggling with deploying all 3 release artifacts via a Deploy to Azure Function jobs. A regular zip deploy will wipe wwwroot before deployment, so when I sequentially do the release in 3 jobs, only the contents of the last zip deployment will be present on the Azure function.

Is there a way to do a 'partial' deploy via the DevOps deploy job, which won't wipe the wwwroot folder; or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your deployment pipeline YAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filesize limit is best bypassed by using a Azure File Share mount - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/scripts/functions-cli-mount-files-storage-linux